# Rules to convert a Javascript Regular Expression pattern to C++ std::regex?

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

I am always confused by the regular expression patterns, not only between languages like javascript, c# and c++, even for a single language, it is so hard for me to remember when every time I try to use it.

I have a javascipt regexp:

```
    var reg = new RegExp(/^.*sdp\":\"(.*)\",.*$/);
```

if I convert it to c++ std::regex, what it should be:

```
    std::regex rgx("/^.*sdp\":\"(.*)\",.*$/"); // is this correct?
```

Is there a rule to convert? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm pretty sure you'll have to escape your backslashes since it's in a string

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the JavaScript regular expression escapes the '"': I don't think it is a special character which needs to be escaped (but I'm not entirely sure). If the quotes need to be escaped in the regular expression you'll need to escape the quote as it otherwise considered to be the end of the string and the backslash when using normal string literals:

```
std::regex rgx("/^.*sdp\\\":\\\"(.*)\\\",.*$/");
```

Since this is pretty much unreadable, C++11 has raw string literals:

```
std::regex rgx(R"(/^.*sdp\":\"(.*)\",.*$/)");
```

Assuming the quote character doesn't need to be escaped for the regular expression, it only needs to be escaped for the string, i.e., you'd indeed, just use

```
std::regex rgx("/^.*sdp\":\"(.*)\",.*$/");
```

This string is one one of the examples where you can't use a simple raw-string literal if you want to use a raw-string literal because it includes the sequence ')"' which would terminate the raw-string literal. You can choose some characters to start and terminate the raw-string literal differently though:

```
std::regex rgx(R"abc(/^.*sdp":"(.*)",.*$/)abc");
```